# Nightmare js running only one time on Linux server

Tags: linux, xvfb, nightmare

Hey I have a nightmare js project that works on my Mac flawlessly but I’m having an issue on the server that it only runs once and then it seems to be not responding at all anymore.
I tried many things from the related GitHub issue using Xvfb and it is starting and working on the first try but not after that, I have to restart it to make it work again.
I was able to find this error message in the pm2 logs of the Xvfb instance but it does not help me much:

> (EE)
>   (EE) 
>   Fatal server error:
>   (EE) Server is already active for display 99
>           If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X99-lock
>           and start again.

What I am getting from this that the screen is live but it cannot use it. 
to start to projects I am running a file that has these contents

```
{


"apps" : [{
    "name"        : "index",
    "script"      : "index.js",
    "env": {
      "DISPLAY": ":99"
    }
  },
    {
      "name"        : "Xvfb",
      "interpreter" : "none",
      "script"      : "Xvfb",
      "args"        : ":99"
    }]
}
```

and i run this with the pm2 start filename command and then i have 2 pm2 processes running.

Comment: Can you attach a little bit of sample code and more details about the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use another Xvfb display like 100.

It is saying there's already an active server because you have Xvfb started on display 99.

To restart it you'll want to do `pm2 restart index`.

As that will just restart the node app and not the Xvfb server which you don't need to do.